# Filter JSON array with objects inside in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, database

I have a particular JSON file that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "objID":"kc6BvvNlVW",
        "string":"bill",
        "createdOn":"2018-09-18T01:51:02",
        "updatedOn":"2018-09-18T01:51:02",
        "number":1,
        "boolean":true,
        "array":["item1","item2"],
        "pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"hYtr54Ds","className":"Users"}
    },
    {
        "objID":"sS1IwFPPWh",
        "string":"tom",
        "createdOn":"2018-09-18T01:59:40",
        "updatedOn":"2018-09-18T01:59:40",
        "number":12.3,
        "boolean":false,
        "array":["item1","item2"],
        "pointer":{"type":"__pointer","objID":"tRe4Fda5","className":"Users"}
    }
]
```

**1.** I need to first check if the **"pointer"** object has `"__pointer"` inside the `type` key and show only the **objID** value in an HTML table, like this:

**"tRe4Fda5"**

Right now, this is how my table looks like:

[image: My HTML table output]

And here's my `foreach` PHP code (into a table row):

```
foreach($jsonObjs as $i=>$obj) {  
  $row_id = $i;    
  echo '<tr>'; 

  foreach($obj as $key => $value){

   // $value is an Array:
   if (is_array($value)) {
      echo '<td>';
      foreach($value as $k=>$v){
         // $v is a Pointer
         if ($v === '__pointer') {

            echo json_encode($v); // <-- WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE ? 

         // $v is an Array:
         } else {
            echo json_encode($v);
         }
       }
       echo '</td>';

      // $value is a Number:
      } else if (is_numeric($value)){
         echo '<td>'.(float)$value.'</td>';

     // $value is a String:
     } else { echo '<td>'.$value.'</td>'; }
  }
```

As you can see in the **pointer** column, the string I get is:

```
"__pointer""hYtr54Ds""Users"
```

with no commas as separators, so this is the line of code I need to edit:

```
echo json_encode($v); // <-- WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE ?
```

I've tried with `echo json_encode($v[$k]['__ponter']);`, but no positive results.

So my final first question is: how can I get each VALUE of the **"pointer"** array?

**2.** Also, the second row of the boolean column shows noting since its value is `false`, shouldn't it show **0**, since the first row shows **1** (true)?

Comment: @VenIfy yes, I've just checked with an echo, it gives TRUE, as it gives TRUE for the other array of only values (no keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look into the object during the second loop to see if it has a property called type and if that property is set to __pointer.

```
foreach($jsonObjs as $i=>$obj) {  
  $row_id = $i;    


  foreach($obj as $key => $value){
    // see if $value has a type property that is set to pointer
    if (isset($value['type']) && $value['type'] == "__pointer") {
      // $value is the pointer object.  Do with it what you will
      echo "<td>" . $value['objID'] . "</td>";
    }

    // more code
  }
}
```

Comment: the problem is that I must use dynamic keys, so you set $obj['pointer'] but the object's name is not always "pointer", it may vary, and that's why I was using all those loops, I must always get the $keys based on the JSON object

Comment: IMO the property name for a structure like your pointer object should always be "pointer", so you can go directly to the pointer rather than fishing around to see if an object contains something that looks like a pointer.

Comment: it worked, thanks so much! What about my 2nd question, about the boolean false value that doesn't get shown as 0?

Comment: PS: although now my 'array' column shows "Array" only, not the "item1""item2" anymore...

Comment: For the boolean you need something like this: `else if (is_bool($value)){ echo '<td>'.($value?'1':'0').'</td>';}`

Comment: thanks so much, I wish i could chat with you for more info, if you're available for hire

Comment: You still need your original code to show the "normal" array, so put your original code after James' if-clause, like this `else if (is_array($value)) {...` and remove the code that was specifically for the pointer

Comment: you're right, I've figured it out a minute ago, it works like a charm, thanks so much! is it possible to privately get in touch with you for some PHP/JSON requests, maybe to hire you?

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
foreach($value as $k=>$v){
         // $v is a Pointer
```

use

```
foreach($value as $k)
{
    //then check for pointer
    if($k->type  === '__pointer')
    {

       echo json_decode($k); //here you will get proper key and value
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, no positive result, I get blank data, it prints out nothing, as shown here: https://i.postimg.cc/DwbTrZRb/json2.png

Comment: above is the answer for your first question. just print json_decode($k) n check if you get a key with value

Comment: I know, but again, it doesn't work on my side, here's what i've done: foreach($obj as $key => $value){ if (is_array($value)) { echo '<td>'; foreach($value as $k){ if($k->type  === '__pointer') {  echo json_decode($k); //here you will get proper key and value  } }

Comment: after this  if($k->type === '__pointer') {  print_r( json_decode($k)); exit; //check here u r getting value with key or not

Comment: and second thing how do you want to store this in your database

Comment: I'm not using a database, but only JSON files :) I'm building a brand new backend using only JSON files, no mySQL involved, nor Node.js